# as3 namespace - get an attribute with a minus sign in it

Tags: actionscript-3, xml-namespaces, e4x, smil

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [e4x / as3: How to access a node with a dash in its name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317404/e4x-as3-how-to-access-a-node-with-a-dash-in-its-name)

I've set the namespace for my XML to use SMIL and I'm able to pull the src attribute of an element this way:

`my.node.@src` which gets "this is some URL"

However, I have another attr called 'system-bitrate'. Because of the minus sign, I can't do `@system-bitrate` So I attempted what I normally do which is `my.node.attribute('system-bitrate')` which isn't working.

Oddly enough, not even `my.node.attribute('src')` works. I suspect this is due to the namespace? So how to I get attributes out using `ny.node.attribute` ?

The only thing that works is `my.node.attributes()[1]`. **I know that's not the "right way" so I'm hoping someone can enlighten me!**

FYI I'm working with [SMIL](http://www.w3schools.com/smil/smil_files.asp) files

** edit **

Here's the namespace required for the XML I'm using:
`default xml namespace = new Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language');`

And an example of the XML I'm working with:

```
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
  <head>
    <meta name="title" content="Live"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video src="myStreamName" system-bitrate="200000"/>
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

** code sample for DennisJaaman **

```
default xml namespace = new Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language');

var xml:XML = XML(event.target.data);
for each(var o:XML in xml.body['switch'].video) {
    if(!hs) hs = o;
    else {
        trace(o.attributes()[1]); // works
                trace(o.@url); // doesn't work either (makes me wonder about NS issues
                trace(o['@system-bitrate']); // doesn't work
                trace(o.attribute('@system-bitrate') // doesn't work
                // etc etc, I just left a few in here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use square brackets like in the sample below:

```
default xml namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language");
var xmlSmpl:XML=<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
  <head>
    <meta name="title" content="Live"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video src="myStreamName" system-bitrate="200000"/>
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>;

trace (xmlSmpl.body['switch']['video']['@system-bitrate']);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to use the following namespace: `default xml namespace = new Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language');`

Comment: I have no idea why that worked, but it did (maybe it was my bad all along?). +1 & answer

Answer (score 2):

Behold! The power of QName!

```
my.node.attribute( 
    new QName( 'http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language', 'system-bitrate' ) 
)
```

The thing about attribute (and descendant, and child...) is that its parameter is type `*` (anonymously). This is because it really isn't a String, it is coerced to a QName (without a URI) in the background. This means you were searching under the default URI for something under the URI above.

Let me know how that code above works out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post:

[e4x / as3: How to access a node with a dash in its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317404/e4x-as3-how-to-access-a-node-with-a-dash-in-its-name)

******EDIT****:

And use the following notation to get XML Attributes that contain a - (dash)

```
trace("Video system-bitrate: " + my.node.video["@system-bitrate"]);
```

These do not work:

```
trace("Video system-bitrate: " + my.node.video.@["system-bitrate"]);
trace("Video system-bitrate: " + my.node.video.attribute("@system-bitrate"));
```

For more info check the [LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_08.html)

Cheers

Comment: They're trying to grab a node whereas I can get the node, just not the attribute :(

Comment: Well, it is still the same principle, please check my edited post

Comment: I tried all those, and for some reason I'm only able to get anything out of `my.node.video.attributes()[1]` which seems so bizarre to me. I would think any of the ways you listed would work too. I'll post my code in an additional edit on my original question.